# How to exclude a certain function from gprof?

Tags: c++, profiler, gprof

I want to profile my code, but I want one function not to count.

I compile as:

`g++ main_no_time.cpp -Wall -std=c++0x -p -pg -O3 -o eg`

and then I run as:

```
./eg Datasets/Klein_nb_P1000_dim10000.txt 16 5 3 1
gprof -Q ./eg > Klein_nb_P1000_dim10000_cpu_rot1.txt
```

The function I want to exclude has this signature.

`void readDivisionSpace(Division_Euclidean_space& ds, char* filename);`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exclude function from flat profile you need use `-P` option:

```
gprof eg gmon.out -P_Z17readDivisionSpaceRiPc > Klein_nb_P1000_dim10000_cpu_rot1.txt
```

For exclude function from call graph you need use `-Q` option:

```
gprof eg gmon.out -Q_Z17readDivisionSpaceRiPc > Klein_nb_P1000_dim10000_cpu_rot1.txt
```

This options can be used in the same time:

```
gprof eg gmon.out -P_Z17readDivisionSpaceRiPc -Q_Z17readDivisionSpaceRiPc > Klein_nb_P1000_dim10000_cpu_rot1.txt
```

Note: `_Z17readDivisionSpaceRiPc` is mangled name of function. For detect mangled name of function option `--no-demangle` can be useful. You can try detect mangled name of function `readDivisionSpace` in the following way:

```
gprof eg gmon.out --no-demangle -Q -b | grep readDivisionSpace
```

Comment: I used 'gprof eg gmon.out -P_readDivisionSpace -Q_readDivisionSpace > Klein_nb_P1000_dim10000_cpu_rot1.txt', but the function still counts. What am I missing? :/

Comment: `_readDivisionSpace` - looks suspicious, is it real mangled name? You can check names with `gprof eg gmon.out --no-demangle -Q -b`.

Comment: I do not know what mangled names are. It's the function I wrote in my question. How should the command be?

Comment: I hope it helps detect name: `gprof eg gmon.out --no-demangle -Q -b | grep readDivisionSpace`.

Comment: Yes it did! Nice. I would suggest you to edit your answer with this info (name detection). Thanks.